# Index name too long on rails activerecord migration. Tried adding index manually, same error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

So I've been successfully creating join tables by using the `name` parameter when adding an index, but I'm not sure why this isn't working when I'm trying to do create a new migration:

```
class CreateVMailCampaignScheduleHours < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :v_mail_campaign_schedule_hours do |t|
      t.belongs_to :v_mail_campaign_schedule, foreign_key: true
      t.string :day
      t.time :start_hours
      t.time :stop_hours

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index [:v_mail_campaign_schedule_hours, :v_mail_campaign_schedule_id], name: :v_mail_campaign_schedule_id
  end
end
```

The error I get is:

> ArgumentError: Index name
>   'index_v_mail_campaign_schedule_hours_on_v_mail_campaign_schedule_id'
>   on table 'v_mail_campaign_schedule_hours' is too long; the limit is 64
>   characters

Any suggestions? I thought my `add_index` would do the trick, but apparently not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change it to the following:

```
class CreateVMailCampaignScheduleHours < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :v_mail_campaign_schedule_hours do |t|
      t.bigint :v_mail_campaign_schedule
      t.string :day
      t.time :start_hours
      t.time :stop_hours

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :v_mail_campaign_schedule_hours, :v_mail_campaign_schedule_id, name: :index_campaign_schedule_hours_on_schedule
  end
end
```

Your approach to create the index manually is the right one. However, `t.belongs_to`, which is an alias for `t.references`, instructs the creation of both the foreign key column and the corresponding index. So Rails still tries to create the index, before reaching `add_index`. Using a simple `t.bigint` doesn't create the index.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, so as previously said, `t.belongs_to` will create an index.

So, I think you can still use `create_join_table`, but you'll just need to specify `index: false` on your belongsTo.

```
create_join_table :v_mail_campaign_schedule_hours do |t|
  t.belongs_to :v_mail_campaign_schedule, foreign_key: true, index: false
  t.string :day
  t.time :start_hours
  t.time :stop_hours

  t.timestamps
  t.index [:v_mail_campaign_schedule_id], name: 'v_mail_campaign_schedule_id'
end
```